# Inject a provider in another provider, same module #1250

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, dependency-injection, nestjs

I have a service/provider, let's say it's call `ServiceA1`, in a module A marked as `@Injectable()`.
In the **same module** I have another service/provider, let's say it's call `ServiceA2`, marked as `@Injectable()`.

I want to inject `ServiceA1` in `ServiceA2` I try with: 
[image: my service]

This code throw an error: `serviceA1 undefined`.

My module.ts

[image: module.ts]

Do I have to make another module to use `serviceA2` in `serviceA1`?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! :-) Please paste your source code as text and format it as code instead of posting screenshots. This makes it easier for others to give answers and find your question when they have a similar problem.

Comment: @KimKern so I try to use your code and in my function this.ServiceA1 is undefined

Answer (score 2):

If you're injecting a service directly by the class, you do not need the `@Inject()`:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA2 {
  constructor(private serviceA1: ServiceA1) {
  }
```

This is the same as:

```
@Injectable()
export class ServiceA2 {
  constructor(@Inject(ServiceA1) private serviceA1: ServiceA1) {
  }
```

---

Note that you injected `@Inject('ServiceA1')` instead of `@Inject(ServiceA1)`. This is matching by a string token instead of a class and can therefore not be resolved.

If you wanted to inject the class by a string token, you would need to declare the provider in your module like this:

```
providers: [
    ServiceA2,
    {provide: 'ServiceA1', useClass: ServiceA1},
]
```

This also works within the same module.

Comment: I tried to do what you say but still do not work. Checkout my repo here:
https://github.com/akelle9582/action-game/blob/master/src/user/services/user.dialogflow.provider.ts
inside function handleEventDebug userService is undefined... thanks a lot for help me

Comment: maybe the problem is in how import my services in module.ts

Comment: I cannot reproduce this with a simple controller. I can inject your UserService just fine. So it must have something to do with the `DialogFlowModule` lib that I don't know. Do you have to inject it in the library first to use it? Also, your dependencies are outdated. You can try `npm update` and also deleting `node_modules` and rerunning `npm install`. Try using the @nest/cli for future projects.

Comment: This was not a problem with nest js decorator but with DialogFlowModule lib, thanks at all for answers

Answer (score 0):

Anyone running into this: make sure you remember to annotate the injected service with `@Injectable`.